# Python C API - catch call to non-existent function

Tags: python, c-api

I need to do some processing in the C backend during runtime. So what I want to do is,
to define a C callback that'd get called each time there's a call to a non-existent python function.

For example:

```
// C code

PyObject* callback_func(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{

    // do stuff here
    return Py_BuildValue("");
}


# python code

print("Hello!")
call_xyz_func()
print("World!")
```

`call_xyz_func` is basically a non-existent python function. So it should call the C callback function and continue with the rest of the python code.

Comment: Nope.  Python isn't extensible at that level.  It will throw an exception.

Comment: That's a shame. I'll have to do it statically I guess

Comment: "Statically"??  I don't know what you mean.  Using a name that doesn't exist results in a `NameError` exception.  Doesn't matter whether it is a function or a variable.

Comment: Yea, thanks for the help. What I meant was I probably gonna create functions for each of my use cases instead of cramming them into a single one. Gonna be a bit tedious but should work I hope.